# Just need to run them on startup. Systemd

Tags: java, screen, systemd, upstart

Ubuntu 19.04
Hi, I have a bug with systemd
I have a **launch-server.service** file that has

```
[Unit]
Description=LaunchServer
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/aborigen/Launcher/LaunchServer/build/libs
Type=notify
User=aborigenserver
Group=sudo
NotifyAccess=all
Restart=always

ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -DmS launchserver /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java -Xmx128M -javaagent:LaunchServer.jar -jar LaunchServer.jar
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S launchserver -X eval 'stuff "stop"\015'
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The algorithm of my actions is as follows:

1. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo nano launch-server.service`

> thereby creating this file and pasting the parameters above

2. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl status launch-server.service`
   and in response:

> ● launch-server.service - LaunchServer Lost Paradise
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/launch-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Active: inactive (dead)

4. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl enable launch-server.service`

> Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/launch-server.service → /etc/systemd/system/launc                                h-server.service.

5. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl status launch-server.service`

> ● launch-server.service - LaunchServer Lost Paradise
>   Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/systemd/system/launch-server.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: inactive (dead)

6. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl start launch-server.service`

> Job for launch-server.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
>   See "systemctl status launch-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

7. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `sudo systemctl status launch-server.service`

aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status launch-server.service

```
● launch-server.service - LaunchServer Lost Paradise
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/launch-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Mon 2019-07-29 12:45:50 EEST; 2h 49min ago
 Main PID: 2496 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Stopped LaunchServer Lost Paradise.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Failed to start LaunchServer Lost Paradise.
aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ chmod +x /home/aborigen/Server/start.sh
aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl start start-server.service
aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl reload start-server.service
Failed to reload start-server.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit start-server.service.
```

8. aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ `journalctl -xe`

eventually:

```
-- Назначен автоматический перезапуск юнита launch-server.service, так как для него был задан
-- параметр Restart=.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Stopped LaunchServer Lost Paradise.
-- Subject: Завершена остановка юнита launch-server.service.
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Процесс остановки юнита launch-server.service был завершен.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: launch-server.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit launch-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'protocol'.
июл 29 12:45:50 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Failed to start LaunchServer Lost Paradise.
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита launch-server.service
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Произошел сбой юнита launch-server.service.
--
-- Результат: failed.
```

I also have start-server.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Lost Paradise Server
After=network.target
After=launch-server.service
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/aborigen/Server/

User=aborigenserver
Group=sudo

Restart=always

ExecStart=/home/aborigen/Server/start.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S ServerAstrey -X eval 'stuff "stop"\015'
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which accordingly:

aborigen@aborigenserver:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo `systemctl status start-server.service`

```
● start-server.service - Lost Paradise Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/start-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-07-29 15:39:26 EEST; 20min ago
Process: 3427 ExecStart=/home/aborigen/Server/start.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 3427 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: start-server.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: start-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Stopped Lost Paradise Server.
июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: start-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: start-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
июл 29 15:39:26 aborigenserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Lost Paradise Server.
```

Already the second day I pull the hair out of my head. I just need to run them on startup. Help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recheck if the exact same command is running in terminal. Then remember that if the service fails it sometimes does not restart immediately but sometimes waits a time. So restarting every few seconds is going to give trouble. If there are too many failures within a certain time the service is stopped permanently.

All this is configured in the Unit section and all this im sure you know already. Therefore I'll give you an example of a working Unit section that has some **surprises** if you look at it carefully.

```
[Unit]
Description=Radmon service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
User=marc
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -u /home/marc/GMC/pyradmon.py
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am sure this will help. (Hint! Sec= )

Answer (score 2):

You have `Active: failed (Result: protocol)` and  `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`, which suggest you're running a background process in the systemd exec command.

If you run your `screen` command on a console, does it put itself in background? That should explain it.

Try using `Type=forking`, that should solve it.

Alternatively, run your `screen` command in foreground, though "attaching" might not work as expected, since a systemd unit is running without a terminal, so screen might fail at that... Perhaps `Type=forking` is the best way to solve this one here...